# Upload image to cloudinary in Django

Tags: python, django, encoding, cloudinary

I am trying to send individual image from HTML to my django view,
using ajax, and upload the image to cloudinary! 
It keeps throwing me below error of encoding! not sure what it is!
Can somebody really help!**

**Code:**

```
<input type="file" name="live" id="live-upload" /> 
var dataimg = new FormData();
dataimg.append('img', $('#live-upload')[0].files[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: '/event/creatives/',
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false, // important 
    contentType: false, // important 
    dataType: 'json',
    data: dataimg
});


import cloudinary
import cloudinary.uploader
import cloudinary.api

cloudinary.config(
  cloud_name="name",
  api_key="key",
  api_secret="secret")

@login_required
def update_creatives(request):
    try:
        cloudinary_response = cloudinary.uploader.upload(request.FILES['img'])
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)
```

**Error:**

```
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 475: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Try removing `dataType: 'json'`, from the ajax request, before trying this inside the `try` block print `request.FILES['img']` and check you are getting the uploaded file or not

Comment: removed! still the same error.. also i m already getting image in request.FILES['img']

Comment: Is the image found in your specified upload dir as you have mentioned in your models.py, if so print the uploaded file URL

Comment: I m not using any field in model for the image, I have to directly upload it

Comment: If so why can't you try to upload the image without coming to your views, Use django template tags to do it.. Try https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary#uploading-images

Comment: I figured it out, by converting image into base64 in my view